# Threshold for BayesShrink

Tags: image, threshold, shrink

I used a Function to calculate Threshold for BayesShrink. Normally the result of the Threshold gives me one value.when I use an image with size 128*128, the code work, but my image has a size of 380*992. the result gives me a Matrix oh threshold 1*992.
please can you help me
with:

- x:the image
- sigmahat=median(abs(x))/0.6745;

this is the code :
   %

```
   function threshold=bayes(X,sigmahat)

   len=length(X);
   sigmay2=sum(X.^2)/len;
   sigmax=sqrt(max(sigmay2-sigmahat.^2,0));
   if sigmax==0 threshold=max(abs(X));
   else threshold=sigmahat.^2/sigmax;
   end
thank you
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a first line to the function:

X = X(:);

Answer (score 0):

According to the original paper of Chang, the image dimensions should be an integer power of 2.